# Combine HTML entity emojis with skin tone modifiers?

Tags: html, unicode, emoji, emoji-tones

How do you combine emoji skin tone modifiers with smileys in normal HTML? I've tried the following in Firefox 52 ESR:

```
 <p>&#128527;&#127995;</p>
 <p>&#127995;&#128527;</p>
 <p>&#x1F60F;&#127995;</p>
 <p>&#127995;&#x1F60F;</p>
```

Which shows up as the smiley and just a circle of the skin tone next to it though not combined:

😏🏻

🏻😏

😏🏻

🏻😏

I do not want to use the literal character. Bonus points for CSS and/or pure JavaScript implementation too (but alone it won't count as the answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like there is no colored “Smirk” emoji. The concept you use should be the right one if used with other emoji.

for example:

👍🏻

would be  `<p>&#x1F44D;&#x1F3FB;</p>`